# Add more than one link to top nav, Magento 2.0

Tags: php, magento2

I'm trying to add more than one non category link to the top nav. I've created a module and it works for adding 1 link but using the following code how would I add several links to the top nav?

```
<?php
namespace atharna\navUpdate\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Topmenu implements ObserverInterface
{

/**
 * @param EventObserver $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menu */
    $menu = $observer->getMenu();
    $tree = $menu->getTree();
    $data = [
        'name'      => __('Test page'),
        'id'        => 'test-page',
        'url'       => 'test-page',
    ];
    $node = new Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
    $menu->addChild($node);
    return $this;
}


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, sir:

```
$menuItems = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Test 1',
            'id' => 'test-item-1',
            'url' => '/test1'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Test 2',
            'id' => 'test-item-2',
            'url' => '/test2'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Test 3',
            'id' => 'test-item-3',
            'url' => '/test3'
        )
    );

    foreach($menuItems as $item){
        $node = new Node($item, 'id', $tree, $menu);
        $menu->addChild($node);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation?